# Issues with mkdbfile in a simple "read a file > Create a hashfile job"

Tags: etl, datastage

Hello datastage savvy people here.

Two days in  a row, the same single datastage job failed (not stopping at all).
The job tries to create a hashfile using the command  /logiciel/iis9.1/Server/DSEngine/bin/mkdbfile /[path to hashfile]/[name of hashfile] 30 1 4 20 50 80 1628 
(last trace in the log)
Something to consider (or maybe not ? ) :
The [name of hashfile] directory exists, and was last modified at the time of execution) but the file D_[name of hashfile] does not.

I am trying to understand what happened to prevent the same incident to happen next run (tonight).
Previous to this day, this job is in production since ever, and we had no issue with it.

Using Datastage 9.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the job log to see if captured an error?  When a DataStage job executes any system command via command execution stage or similar methods, the stdout of the called job is captured and then added to a message in the job log.  Thus if the mkdbfile command gives any output (success messages, errors, etc) it should be captured and logged.  The event may not be flagged as an error in the job log depending on the return code, but the output should be there.

If there is no logged message revealing cause of directory non-create, a couple of things to check are:
-- Was target directory on a disk possibly out of space at that time?
-- Do you have any Antivirus software that scans directories on your system at certain times?  If so, it can interfere with I/o.  If it does a scan at same time you had the problem, you may wish to update the AV software settings to exclude the directory you were writing dbfile to.